# How to change python version to rc or something else?

Tags: python, pip, version

We have python package and using [pbr](https://pypi.org/project/pbr/) which get the version from git repo. Its working fine, but when I create dist, it add `.dev1` to the version.

```
dist/
  my_lib.0.1.1.dev1-py3-none-any.whl
```

My git repo has latest tag as `0.1.0`. Is there any way to control this version? like when I do `python setup.py sdist` I can give like which version I want to change. Means I have to change this to `1.0.0` or `0.2.0` or `0.1.0rc1` or any other way.

I know there is package [bumpversion](https://pypi.org/project/bumpversion/) which I used in past for the version control. Now checking if is there any way to do that.